# C# delegates hiding

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm learning Delegates.
I simply writing 2 functions that returns a string each and then i hide them inside a delegate like this:

```
    delegate string PrinterDelegate();
class Printer
{
    public PrinterDelegate BlackColor = PrintBlackColor;
    public PrinterDelegate Color = PrintColor;

    private static string PrintBlackColor()
    {
        return "Printing black color";
    }
    private static string PrintColor()
    {
        return "Printing with color";
    }

    public string Returner(Func<string> func)
    {
        return func();
    }
}
```

(I will say what Returner is after i will ask my question)
so the program.cs looks like this:

```
Printer printer = new Printer();
Func<string> mainPrinter = () => { return printer.BlackColor(); };
string totogate = printer.Returner(mainPrinter);
Console.WriteLine(totogate);
```

and of course i get:
"Printing black color" in the console.
now what i'm not able to understand is this line:

```
Func<string> mainPrinter = () => { return printer.BlackColor(); };
```

What does it mean to return a PrinterDelegate named BlackColor under mainPrinter which is Func?
what does mainPrinter hold?
and when i pass mainPrinter into Returner, what is it that returns into the string name totogate?
i know it will return the "Printing black color", but how?
What happens exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down:

```
Func<string> mainPrinter = () => { return printer.BlackColor(); };
```

- `Func<string> mainPrinter` declares a variable that has the type `Func<string>`
- `=` assigns it eh the value `() => { return printer.BlackColor(); }`
- `() => { return printer.BlackColor(); }` is the interesting part and is lambda syntax to declare an anonymous function that takes no arguments returns a string.  The compiler looks at the return statement to infer its return type.

Altogether the statement declares a delegate for a function with no arguments that returns a string (see [`Func<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx)).  The delegate is assigned to a reference to the anonymous function declared as `{return printer.BlackColor;}`.

Comment: So in short, Func<string> is a delegate that accepts function of return type string and in my case, i returned printer.BlackColor which is actually the function PrintBlackColor of return type string, which now, mainPrinter holds.   of course i pass it to Returner and func() of course refers to PrintBlackColor as well.!          Assuming i'm not wrong in what i wrote, i'm grateful.

Comment: Bingo!  Got it in one.

Answer (score 0):

You told:

> I'm learning Delegates.

Ok, and this is the specific of Func<string>:

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>();
```

Exactly, Func is a Delegate. So, from MSDN:

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type.

Your Func represents a reference to a methods with no parameter list and return a string.
You can think like a variable that can store a func instead of int or string:

```
Func<string> mainPrinter = () => { return printer.BlackColor(); };
```

mainPrinter is a variable that store a function, () => { return printer.BlackColor(); } function.

So, like read a int variable, you can execute a Func variable ;-)